# Add character after a value sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need of add character after a value sql field in auto mode.  Example i have numeryc type  fields 01 and i wanna add after the number PC so trasform the value in 01PC.

help me?

Comment: Downvoted for being unclear and having bad grammar.

Comment: "Auto mode" means what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query add the letter A at the end of field1

```
 select concat(field1, 'A') from table1
```

And if you wanna update the table you can do..

```
 update table1 SET field1 = concat(field1, 'A')
```

The last query add letter A at the end of all field1

Comment: Federico! sei Italiano? Ora provo subito, grazie!

Comment: Funziona, ma non c'è modo di memorizzarli sul database. Tipo con update? Ho provato con phpmyadmin ma lo seleziona e basta!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `convert` sql function like so
`select concat(convert(nvarchar([length]), field1), 'pc') from table1`